# Git LFS is not able to push all branches and commits

Tags: git, github, migration, git-lfs, aws-codecommit

I am migrating Code COmmit Repos to github using LFS because those are large in size . and Also i Want to push push all the branches and their commits . But unable to perform.
git LFS push only one commit related to one main branch only .

i tried to push but there is is only one branch exists remotely .

Comment: By default, `git push` will just push one branch. You can specify the names of the branches (and tags) you want to push, or if you know you want to push all branches use `--all`. And if you want to push tags too, `--tags`. For details, try `git push --help`. With LFS the branch logic should still be the same.